# Unity 2D- Rays not going in the right direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I have a game object which is supposed to shoot a beam in several directions. I want to keep it as flexible as possible so I added several targets, which a script will draw a ray(from the game object to the target). I have used the position variable of the target's transforms but that just caused all the rays to go off to a strange direction but did slightly change when i moved around. Then i tried the local position of the targets but that caused all the rays to go in their original direction, not accounting for a change in rotation.

Here is the code for the laser's script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour {
    private LineRenderer Linerenderer;
    public List<Transform> rays;

    void Start()
    {
        Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
    }
    void Update () {

        foreach (Transform tran in rays)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, tran.position,20);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

[-Using world positions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghUKR.png)

[-Using local positions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Fev.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, after  bit of messing around I was finally able to get it to work.
If anyone else needs help with something similar (Dynamic ray-casting).
Here is the final code(you might have to edit it slightly):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour {
    private LineRenderer Linerenderer;
    public List<Transform> rays;

    void Start()
    {
        Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;

    }
    void Update()
    {

        foreach (Transform tran in rays)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector3(-1, -1, 0));
            Vector2 direction = (tran.position - transform.position).normalized;
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction);
            Vector2 rayDirection = (hit.point - new Vector2( transform.position.x, transform.position.y));
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDirection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Physics2D.Raycast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) method's second parameter you are specifying is wrong: it should not be a **position in space**, but a **direction**. The second parameter for the [Debug.DrawRay()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) method is **also a direction**, not a **point in space**.

Try the following:

```
void Update () {

    foreach (Transform tran in rays)
    {
        Vector2 direction = (tran.position - transform.position).normalized;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, 20);

        Vector2 rayDirection = hit.point - transform.position;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDirection);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Skalex I just read your post below.. I just edited this answer and fixed the `Debug.DrawRay()` call. Try out the new code and see if it is working now.